# how to change the button size on title bar on xwayland?

Tags: linux, qt, yocto, wayland

I'm working on a yocto platform with Qt5 + xwayland backend, there is a issue that the buttons on title bar like close/maximum are too small to click, I changed **QT_WAYLAND_FORCE_DPI** but it only affects the client area but not title bar. and I changed **scale** in weston.ini but it doesn't work. can anybody give some tips? thanks in advance.

Djiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I returned to this project and find the way to solve the issue, the title bar is decorated by qt, so just modify the files in wayland/src/plugins/decorations/bradient.